Understanding the Proof of the Converse for Colossally Abundant Numbers
I'm trying to understand the proof of the converse statement in Proposition 3 in Erdös regarding colossally abundant numbers. The same proposition is in Broughan's book with the same proof but claims that the converse is proved. The proposition states:

Proposition: Let $ N $ be a colossally abundant number for some $ \epsilon $, and let $ p $ be any prime such that $ p^\alpha \parallel N $ (i.e., $ p^\alpha $ is the highest power of $ p $ dividing $ N $). Then:
$$
 F(p, \alpha + 1) \leq \epsilon \leq F(p, \alpha).
 $$
Conversely, if $ N $ is a positive integer such that for all primes $ p $ with $ p^\alpha \parallel N $, we have
$$
 F(p, \alpha + 1) \leq \epsilon \leq F(p, \alpha),
 $$
then $ N $ is colossally abundant for $ \epsilon $.

The forward direction is clear, but I'm not sure how the proof demonstrates the converse. From what I can see, the proof shows calculations for certain divisors involving primes $ p $ and $ Np $, but it is not immediately clear how this establishes the converse.
Could someone explain how the converse part of the lemma is proven, if it is indeed proven here?
